# Input::File() displaying 'NULL' when using mini ajax file upload plugin in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4

I have a form with mini ajax file upload plugin.. and i am trying to submit the form with file with other input fields.

when i am using only the upload plugin without using other input fields the plugin working fine.. but when i save field values first  and upload the files afterwards it is giving NULL value..

url for the form : http://visualquotes.co.nz/record-job

Working fine when using like this

```
$file = Input::file('upl');
var_dump($file);

$new_user = new User;
$new_user->name = Input::get('name');
$new_user->email = Input::get('email');
$new_user->save();
```

Not Working

```
$new_user = new User;
$new_user->name = Input::get('name');
$new_user->email = Input::get('email');
$new_user->save();

$file = Input::file('upl');
var_dump($file);
```

after i use input::get(),  file value null.. need help??

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us please your view? 
I think you just have to add this to your Form if your using illuminate/Html

> 'files' => true

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply i am using like below  <form id="upload" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" files = 'true'>

Comment: <form id="upload" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" files = 'true'>
<div id="upload_file"><input type="file" name="upl" multiple /></div>      
<input type="text" class="form-control " id="title" name="title" >                                                            
 </form>